# Providing Mathematica with a "known" antiderivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement

Suppose, I wanted to calculate some definite (or indefinite) integral in Mathematica:
$$\int_a^bf(x)\mathrm{d}x$$
Normally, this can be done using

```
Integrate[f[x], {x, a, b}]
```

which will give the result.

However, there are cases where no antiderivative exists for $f$. What I want to do is to "trick" Mathematica into thinking, that there exists some antiderivative $F(x)$ of $f$, even if this function would normally not be expressible in terms of "elementary functions". 
That is, I want the above code to return

```
F[b] - F[a]
```

instead of returning the integral unevaluated. This may then be further simplified when I provide some expression for $F$, for example some approximation for the antiderivative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`TagSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f /: Integrate[f[x_], {x_, a_, b_}] := F[b] - F[a]

Integrate[f[y], {y, lb, ub}]

(* -F[lb] + F[ub] *)
```